# Access problem with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray, tableview

my problem is that I can't access my NSMutableArray in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}.

I create my NSMutableArray here:

```
nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"/xml/items/item/short_desc" error:nil];

if (nodes != nil && [nodes count] >= 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [nodes count]; i++) {
        CXMLElement *resultElement = [nodes objectAtIndex:i];
        result = [[[[resultElement attributeForName:@"data"] stringValue] copy] autorelease];       
        [short_desc addObject:result];
    }
}
```

and I can print out the content of short_desc everywhere with:

```
NSLog([short_desc objectAtIndex:0]);
```

but not in (if I do so, my app crashes):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

.....

NSString *date = [name objectAtIndex:0];


labelDate.text = date;
.....   

return cell;}
```

if I use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

.....

NSString *date = @"text...";


labelDate.text = date;
.....   

return cell;}
```

it works correctly.

ANY SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM???

Comment: Not related to your question but don't do this: `NSLog([short_desc objectAtIndex:0]);`, do this: `NSLog(@"%@", [short_desc objectAtIndex:0]);`  the reason being that if the string in the first case contains any % escapes, you'll crash.

Comment: Also, you must be getting compiler warnings on that NSLog, if you are, **do not ignore them**. If you are not, turn on the `-Wall` flag and also set the "run static analyzer" option in your build settings. chance are that will flag your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work with NSLog(@"%@", [short_desc objectAtIndex:0]); also; If I add this line, my app crashes

Answer (score 3):

You dont show how you create the array, but the most likely cause is that you are not retaining your array and its being released before u hit the method that crashes. How are you creating the name array?..
Right so you see you are creating the array like so 
62.        name = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
you need to retain the array otherwise the OS will release the memory and you wont bea ble to access it...instead you can do

```
name =[ [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain];
```

The poster below me posted an article about memory managment you should go over that...here is a link anyway [memory managment guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)

Comment: NSMutableArray *short_desc;short_desc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

Answer (score 0):

If you create array using using methods with "alloc", "new", or "copy" word in method name - you don't need to retain array. In other cases created array is authoreleased array. If you want to store it - you should increase retain counter by sending `retain` method (e.g. `[names retain]`). And don;t forget to release it when you finish using it (e.g. in `dealloc` method).

Please read [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

Comment: short_desc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; returns autoreleased array. 
use:
short_desc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[short_desc retain];

Comment: for your code (from link) you should create arrays like that:

short_desc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

name = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

location = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

startDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

and in dealloc method you should do:

[short_desc release];

[name release];

etc...

Comment: short_desc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10]; worked fine! Thanks!